# xcopy on Batch file for backup server

Tags: windows-server-2012, batch-file

i have 5 servers connected and want to backup a folder on servers  1,2,3,4  to server 5 and folder on server 5 to server 1.

i write a batch file that use xcopy to copy the folders.
my question is if it's better to create one batch file on server 5 to copy all folders to him in an order or to create a batch file for every server to put the files in server 5.

my code

```
xcopy  \\xxx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\inetpub\wwwroot C:\backupData\wwwrootxxx\ /H /D /E /EXCLUDE:C:\bak\exckudelist.txt /Y /C /Z /R
```

today the copy take too much time. i need a backup of the folders

Comment: Did you try robocopy instead of xcopy? For convinience I would perform the _backup_ tasks in just one server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest you the first approach: to create a single file on server5 and let it copy the required files. It is better to have the backup jobs centralized.

Also, I second the suggestion to use robocopy, as it is significantly more advanced than xcopy.